# Ошибка при парсинге json в android

Tags: java, android, json, io, gson

Есть json, который лежит в папке assets проекта в таком формате:

```
[
  {
    "genre": "Поп",
    "stations": [
      {
        "stream": "https://rusradio.hostingradio.ru/rusradio96.aacp",
        "name": "Русское Радио",
        "image": "https://images.radiovolna.net/_files/images/stations/322/yn0d58d0d9432c7fc016444329.jpg"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Класс Radio:

```
public class Radio {

    private String genre;
    private ArrayList<Station> stations;

    public Radio(String genre, ArrayList<Station> stations){
        this.genre = genre;
        this.stations = stations;
    }

    public void setName(String genre) {
        this.genre = genre;
    }

    public void setStations(ArrayList<Station> stations) {
        this.stations = stations;
    }

    public String getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }

    public ArrayList<Station> getStations() {
        return stations;
    }
}
```

Класс Station:

```
public class Station {
    private String mName;
    private String mStream;
    private String mImage;

    public Station(String name, String stream, String image){
        this.mName = name;
        this.mStream = stream;
        this.mImage = image;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.mName = name;
    }

    public void setStream(String stream) {
        this.mStream = stream;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.mImage = image;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return mImage;
    }

    public String getStream() {
        return mStream;
    }
}
```

Класс JSONHelper:

```
public class JSONHelper {


    private static final String JSON_FILE = "radio.json";

    static List<Radio> importFromJSON(Context context){
        InputStreamReader streamReader = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;

        try{
            inputStream = context.getAssets().open(JSON_FILE, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            streamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            DataItems dataItems = gson.fromJson(streamReader, DataItems.class);
            return  dataItems.getRadios();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (streamReader != null){
                try {
                    streamReader.close();
                } catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (inputStream != null){
                try{
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static class DataItems {
        private List<Radio> radios;

        List<Radio> getRadios() {
            return radios;
        }
    }
}
```

Из MainActivity вызываю JSONHelper и пытаюсь передать хоть какое-то значение в лог:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayList<Radio> radioArray = new ArrayList<>();
        radioArray = (ArrayList<Radio>) JSONHelper.importFromJSON(getApplicationContext());

        if (radioArray != null) {
            for (Radio r : radioArray)
                Log.d("debug", r.getGenre());
        }
        else Log.d("debug", "no");
    }
}
```

В строке JSONHelper:

```
DataItems dataItems = gson.fromJson(streamReader, DataItems.class);
```

Вылезает исключение:

```
com.google.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.illegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY
```

Что делаю не так?

Comment: во-первых- в ошибке указано что вы ждете объект а приходит массив, во вторых на какую строку указывает ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в корне json массив(`[]`) объектов, а не объект(`{}`).
Либо уберите квадратные скобки вначале и конце, либо конвертируйте в массив/список и берите данные из него соответствующим образом.
Плюс элемент этого массива соответствует классу `Radio` - значит можно получить сразу список объектов `Radio`, а `DataItems` сюда не подходит.
Насколько я могу судить по логике представленного кода, должно быть так:

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Radio>>(){}.getType();
ArrayList<Radio> radios = gson.fromJson(streamReader, listType);
return  radios;
```

Comment: см. конец файла JSONHelper, там описан класс DataItems

Comment: Не заметил, но это сути не меняет - этот класс не нужен, вместо него нужно получать сразу список, как в моём ответе. Ну или вдруг вам так удобнее, то создать его из полученного списка.

Comment: При парсинге объекты Station внутри полей содержат null значения, при этом размер списка Station в Radio верный. В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: Изменил название полей в классе Station на прописные - заработало.

Comment: Да, поля должны быть названы так же как в json. Либо имя json-поля, откуда надо взять значение, должно быть задано аннотацией `@SerializedName("name")`